# Nested React routing with params issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I have a task to do where I'm given a set of routes that I must implement and I find it somewhat confusing due to how its structured. So, rather than explaining it, I'll share the code of the routes themselves:

```
  <Switch>
    <Route exact={true} path="/products" component={ProductList} />
    <Route path={"/products/:id"} component={ProductPreview} />
    <Route exact={true} path={"/products/create"} component={ProductNew} />
    <Route path={"/products/:id/edit"} component={ProductEdit} />
  </Switch>
```

The paths I have to implement in the router are as follows:

```
/products
/products/{id}
/products/create
/products/{id}/edit
```

My issue is that when i go past the "/products" path, it only seems to render the ProductPreview component and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like i've been able to solve it by moving the routes around a bit and setting them to look for the exact path.

```
     <Switch>
        <Route exact={true} path={"/products"} component={ProductList} />
        <Route exact={true} path={"/products/create"} component={ProductNew} />
        <Route exact={true} path={"/products/:id"} component={ProductPreview} />
        <Route exact={true} path={"/products/:id/edit"} component={ProductEdit} />
      </Switch>
```

Comment: Switching “/create” to come before “/:id” was a good move.  The router looks for the first match, so best practice is that you should list more specific route paths first.  I would personally put “:id/edit” before “/:id” for the same reason.  It won’t make a difference since you are using exact match, but that order allows for the possibility of non-exact match whereas your current order doesn’t.

Answer (score 0):

Just change first router path from `/products` to `/products/list` and it should work fine. Currenty it will always match second route (`/products/:id`), cause nothing (`undefined`) is also "valid" `id`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i bet that would have worked, however I must use the exact paths as specified in the question...